# Force touch in iOS or Apple Watch

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, apple-watch

Is it possible to somehow detect how much force someone pushes a force touch. Like can I know if one press was harder than another?

Comment: Not on iOS. On Apple Watch, it is possible.

Comment: How i can detect force touch.? would you please provide me any reference , tutorial or something like. @rebello65

Comment: Currently there are none: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27077887/watchkit-api-for-force-touch-digital-crown Wait until after Monday - maybe there will new APIs after the WWDC

Answer (score 0):

Right now developers have Full Access to Mac OS X Force Touch only, WatchKit ForceTouch is not even mentioned in the API so you can't expect yo use this function in your app. Just like said in the comments, WWDC is in this week wait to see the announcements, maybe they release something.

Hope it Helps.

Answer (score 0):

Force Touch APIs are the following:

- For Apple Watch: There is no API available, but you can use the context menus. If Apple Watch detects a Force Touch, it will open the context menu associated for your app. See Apple Watch Programming Guide book form Apple for more details about context menu (Force Touch) APIs.
- For Macbook: There are APIs for the new Force Touch trackpad in the new Macbook introduced in March 2015, and more will be available after WWDC15 (June 8-12, San Fransisco).
- For iOS: There is no Force Touch compatible screen available for any of iOS devices, but APIs may be introduced in WWDC15 (June 8-12, San Francisco).

Update: In WWDC15, they introduced Force Touch APIs and a lot of other APIs for watchOS 2, but nit for iOS 9.

Comment: I think Force Touch APIs are still not available in Apple Watch OS 2

Comment: See WWDC 2015 Session Videos for more details about the new APIs, including What's new in watchOS 2.