# Monitor value of Digital Crown? (Watch OS 2)

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to read the value of the Digital Crown on my Apple Watch.

I've read that `WKInterfacePicker` makes that possible, but I'm not really looking for picking an item from a list, I want to do read the value of the
Digital Crown and use that value for something inside the app.

For example to move a visual object sideways.

Is this possible? If yes then how can I utilize the Digital Crown?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WatchKit API for Force Touch / Digital Crown?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27077887/watchkit-api-for-force-touch-digital-crown)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an Apple Dev Forum thread: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/7580#7580

The user Svarrall explained how to do it as of current Watch OS 2.

> svarrall Jun 11, 2015 1:16 AM (in response to limtc) It should be
>   possible indirectly.   Use an InterfacePicker and add a dummy array to
>   it with the same number of steps as the Slider, but don't show the
>   picker in the interface (It's minimum dimensions seem to be 2x2, not
>   sure if it's still accessible if it's Hidden, haven't tried) then in
>   the Picker's @IBAction func pickerAction(value: Int) use that to
>   update the value of the Slider to match.   If you set the Picker's
>   focus style to None and Indicator to Disabled then no-one needs to
>   know it's there. In code setting picker.focusForCrownInput() will make
>   it priority for input.   The only issue I've seen with this, is if the
>   Interface is longer than the screen the crown reverts to scrolling the
>   page itself and not the picker. Oh and it's a bit slow to get the
>   picker updates (on device, not simulator)

Answer (score 1):

Just to update this question. In WatchOS3 it is now possible to read the value of the Digital Crown.

Apple introduced [WKCrownSequencer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkcrownsequencer) that gives you updates on the crown state.